# Is there a way of knowing which part of an OR statement is true then returning it in python

Tags: python

i just want to return the variable that was less than to 2

```
if x < 2 or y < 2:
    return x or y
```

im just wondering if theres an easy way to do this because only thing i can think of is just using 2 different if statements

Comment: What do you propose to return if neither value is less than 2? Also, for any practical purpose surely you would need to know which value was less than 2

Comment: No, you need to rewrite it as an if/elif block

Comment: What do you propose to return if *both* values are less than 2 but not the same?

Comment: Please show the working version that you "think of" so we can better understand what the code shall do.

Comment: please provide the expected outputs for the following cases: `x=0, y=3` ; `x=3, y=0` ; `x=0, y=0` ; `x=3, y=3`.

Comment: What can x and y possibly be? Are they maybe guaranteed to be non-negative integers or so?

Answer (score 5):

You could remember what you last checked:

```
if (z := x) < 2 or (z := y) < 2:
    return z
```

But I'd prefer the ordinary:

```
if x < 2:
    return x
if y < 2:
    return y
```

Or in some cases perhaps a loop:

```
for z in x, y:
    if z < 2:
        return z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get the first value that matches your condition, the could generalize to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
# as many variables as you want
# w,x,y,z = 3,2,1,0
return next(filter(lambda x: x<2, [w,x,y,z]), None)
```

output: `1`

*NB. of course this becomes interesting if you have many variables, for just 2 prefer a double return*

Comment: This is not equivalent, as it *always* returns, makes following code unreachable. Haven't checked filter+lambda, but I suspect it's about as bad as map+lambda (inferior to the generator expression).

Comment: @Kelly yes that's true, if there is a following code. OP didn't answer to my comment so I am not sure what is expected in case of not/multiple match. Regarding efficiency, unless there are thousands of variables, I think it's just a matter of preference here.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

> `min()`
> function.

```
if x < 2 or y < 2:
    return min(x,y)
```

explanation:
if one of them smaller than 2 then it should be smallest one, logically.

However, if both smaller than 2 then you should implement xor door for obtain correct result.

Comment: for x = 1 and y=-1, this will return -1, but evaluation is done on x only so did n't process y,

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for

Comment: then he can basically use xor door for it

Comment: @j1-lee which part of condition is true , so by technically expression which evalute first should be return, but here only minimum is return . what this will fail when x=1 y =-10, so this solution only re turn -10, but in code only x = 1 is evaluated and it got true and returned and y=-10 is not evalaueted. so if a value is not evaluated so that cant be a answer

Comment: that's an hypothetical situation, he can add one more and condition and fix that issue, if you bring real-life problem then we can talk clearly how this method can solve problems without additional if and else

Comment: What is "xor door"?